# UITableViewCell similar to iPhone contact cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to programmatically create a `UITableViewCell` similar to the cell that  we can see in iPhone contact app for entering mobile number. How to do??  How to draw that vertical line?

[image]

Comment: For a vertical line it's better if you use a image.

Answer (score 1):

[image: This how it'll look a like.]

You'll have to create a custom `UITableViewCell` to create this. In your custom `UITableViewCell` you'll have to create following things :

1. Background Image for the cell. It can be either a background image(Which will include rounded corner and a separator line) or you can also create the effect with `UIView` by rounding the corner. Yellow box.
2. `UILable` to show text "mobile". Red box.
3. `UITextField` with placeholder "Phone". Orange box.

Comment: How to draw that vertical line? is that background image?

Comment: @Anil : yes. You use the background image for line. As i've seen in image in my answer. The whole yellow part you'll have to take as a image

Answer (score 0):

customize the `UITableViewCell` with your own implementation. Take one `UItableViewCell` subclassed `View` and draw/add your implementation in that.